# Default path in node.js terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal

Can i change default path in node.js terminal? I have my projects in one folder so every time i need type same path, it's not big problem but maybe it's easy to set ;)

Answer (score 0):

[You should check this out.](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)

Basically, you can set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to add a path of your other project. Then node will try to look there to load modules and you don't have to give a relative or absolute path to a node module.

Comment: I don't mean path to node module but for example when i want type "npm start" or git commands i need reach this (always same) folder in terminal.

Comment: Like "D:", "cd projects\project1" and then in this place im using node or git commands.